# Get maximum (more than 20) results in Google map API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

i am using `Google maps API version 3` and text search for places using javascript.

But I only get 20 results.

How do I  get more than 20 results (say, around 100 or 200)?

Comment: Afaik you can get a maximum of 60 results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default is 20, but there can be as much as 60. However they'll be on subsequent pages, see the [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#PlaceSearchPaging) and the [example here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search-pagination) for how to handle the pagination that's required.