# More than 20 results using Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get maximum (more than 20) results in Google map API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194871/get-maximum-more-than-20-results-in-google-map-api)

I need a more than 20 results for google map textsearch function. Now I want to know the maximum results and how to get more than 20 results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default, each Place search returns up to 20 establishment results
>   per query; however, each search can return as many as 60 results,
>   split across three pages. Additional pages are available via the
>   PlaceSearchPagination object. In order to access additional pages you
>   must capture the PlaceSearchPagination object via a callback function.

More information here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#PlaceSearchPaging